# Why are credit card companies generally limiting themselves to 16-digit data infrastructure?

Tags: credit-card

I have a question.

Why are credit card companies generally limiting themselves to 16-digit data infrastructure?

Comment: I'm not seeing a security question here.

Comment: Why not? they seem to be doing alright these days...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[ISO/IEC 7812](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_7812)** is a very old standard that has a relatively large address space even taking into account the **[Luhn algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm)** used and the agreed upon **[Issuer Identification Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_card_number)**. Modern analytics to detect fraud can also easily deal with the card numbers being reused over time which allows number reuse to be fairly easy.

That said, more than anything it's just an older standard that probably takes a lot of effort to upgrade.

Sometimes when updating standards if there is no rush to deploy the change the standards bodies will also wait and watch what is happening in the industry in case they need to change their design before a new update is released. **Given the large amount of software that would have to be updated I suspect they won't recommend a change unless it's absolutely required.**